# What is the meaning of "stand for public office"?

Tags: meaning

In Drama film/Biography film *The People vs. Larry Flynt (1996)*, Preacher, Jerry Falwell filed a case on Larry Flynt, Hustler Magazine, in supreme court for potraying his image in satrical parody way in
Hustler magazine. So Chief Justice said this words after hearing 
Alan Isaacman,Larry Flynt's lawyer words.

> Mr. Isaacman, the First Amendment is not everything. It's a very
>   important value, but it's not the only  value in our society. What
>   about a value which says good people can enter public life and public
>   service? The rule you give us says that if **you stand for public office**
>   or become a public figure, you cannot protect yourself or indeed your
>   mother against a parody of your committing incest with her in an
>   outhouse. Do you think George Washington would've stood for office if
>   that was the consequence?

What is the meaning of “stand for public office”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionary [entry for **stand**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stand) gives this meaning in **definition 5**:

> Be a candidate in an election. Example ‘he stood for parliament in
>   1968’.

There is an expandable list giving many other examples of similar usage.